# Is this statement equivalent to the axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice, foundations

The statement is:

For every family $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ of mutually disjoint, non-empty sets, there exists a set $S$ which contains exactly one element from each $S_i$.

I know AOC implies this, but does it work the other way around?

Comment: The answer is yes, but what exactly is your version of the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Anonymous The standard version, as far as I can tell, is that for any set $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ of non-empty sets, there is a function $f : \{S_i\}_{i \in I} \to \cup_{i \in I}S_i$ such that $f(S_i) \in S_i$ for every $i \in I$.

Comment: If the $S_i$'s are meant to be a family, it complicates things a bit that $f$ takes $S_i$ as an argument rather than $i$. In that case, it's cleaner to formulate the axiom without the indexing set $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a set of non-empty sets on which we wish to define a choice function. Then the sets $\{S\} \times S$, for $S \in E$, are disjoint and nonempty. If $f$ consists of one element of each of these sets, then the required choice function can be selected to be $f$.

(If you don't have the replacement schema, you can show that the collection of sets $\{S\} \times S$ form a set. This collection is a subset of $P[P(E \times \bigcup E)].$)